# I cannot run php executable path

Tags: php, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to set up a contact form for a webpage; I installed homebrew and I configured a php executable path thus:

"php.validate.executablePath": "/opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.2/php.ini",

However, the following error appears:

spawn /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.2/php.ini EACCES

I have no idea how to fix this problem. Any idea how to do it?

Here's a screenshot that might prove useful:

[Spaen EACCESS problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcD2Q.png)

Comment: `php.ini` is not an _executable_ file

Comment: Thanks! But that still doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: That alone won't help, you need to change the path/executable. What did you change it to?

Comment: I changed it to /opt/homebrew/bin/php, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you by chance asking how to configure the builtin PHP extension in Visual Studio Code? That doesn't have anything to do with installing PHP or running your code. And I'd recommend anyway to disable that extension and switch to PHP Intelephense.